# CSS transition is not working when expanding tree

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, transition

I'm building a `TreeView` using plain CSS and JS and now I want to add a little bit transition effect on expanding/collapsing the node. The transition works on **collapsing** but not working on **expanding** action. I use `max-height` value for the transition value.

Here is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/justinus-hermawan/pen/RwoGKmq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed your `transition: all .4s ease;` and used `transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;`

Also i've added the above to

```
.tree .node.active > .subitems {
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

*Note* in the demo below, I've added a `setTimeout` in your js to make the `+`/`-` change after animation. You can simply just use your js if you don't like the effect.

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#tree .node .toggler').on('click', function() {
    var obj = this;
    $(this).closest('.node').toggleClass('active').find('.subitems').slideToggle();
    if ($(obj).closest('.node').hasClass('active')) {
      $(obj).html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-12v-2h12v2z"/></svg>');
    } else {
      $(obj).html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z"/></svg>');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 5em;
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.tree {
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}

.tree,
.tree .subitems {
  margin: 0 0 0 1.2em;
  /* indentation */
  color: #1a73e8;
}

.tree .subitems {
  margin-left: .6em;
  /* (indentation / 2) */
  display:none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tree:before,
.tree .subitems:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.tree .node {
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  /* indentation + .5em */
  line-height: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tree .node:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  /* equals to indentation */
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* border top width */
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  /* (line-height / 2) */
  left: 0;
}

.tree .node:last-child:before {
  background: white;
  height: auto;
  top: 1em;
  /* (line-height / 2) */
  bottom: 0;
}

.tree .node .display,
.tree .node .display>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .25em;
}

.tree .node .display {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tree .node .display .icon {
  line-height: 0;
}

.tree .node .display .icon svg {
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
}

.tree .node .display .icon.toggler {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tree .node .display .options {
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 4.35em;
  /* (3 * icon width) + (3 * icon margin-right) */
  margin-left: .25em;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: visibility .1s linear, opacity .1s linear;
}

.tree .node .display .options .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .25em;
}

.tree .node .display:hover .options {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tree .node.active>.subitems {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Tree</p>
<div id="tree" class="tree">
  <div class="node">
    <div class="display">
      <div class="icon toggler">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="name">Animals</div>
      <div class="options">
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subitems">
      <div class="node">
        <div class="display">
          <div class="name">Birds</div>
          <div class="options">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="node">
        <div class="display">
          <div class="icon toggler">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z" />
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="name">Mammals</div>
          <div class="options">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitems">
          <div class="node">
            <div class="display">
              <div class="name">Elephant</div>
              <div class="options">
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="node">
            <div class="display">
              <div class="name">Mouse</div>
              <div class="options">
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="node">
        <div class="display">
          <div class="name">Reptiles</div>
          <div class="options">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <div class="display">
      <div class="icon toggler">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="name">Plants</div>
      <div class="options">
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subitems">
      <div class="node">
        <div class="display">
          <div class="icon toggler">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z" />
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="name">Flowers</div>
          <div class="options">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subitems">
          <div class="node">
            <div class="display">
              <div class="name">Rose</div>
              <div class="options">
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="node">
            <div class="display">
              <div class="name">Tulip</div>
              <div class="options">
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="node">
        <div class="display">
          <div class="name">Trees</div>
          <div class="options">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm7 14h-5v5h-4v-5h-5v-4h5v-5h4v5h5v4z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-5 17l1.006-4.036 3.106 3.105-4.112.931zm5.16-1.879l-3.202-3.202 5.841-5.919 3.201 3.2-5.84 5.921z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm4.151 17.943l-4.143-4.102-4.117 4.159-1.833-1.833 4.104-4.157-4.162-4.119 1.833-1.833 4.155 4.102 4.106-4.16 1.849 1.849-4.1 4.141 4.157 4.104-1.849 1.849z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, it works man. But, Im still wondering why there's a delay when we trying to collapse it (right after we click the toggler), it's about 1s long.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan I've changed the code so it uses slideToggle() and not max-height. give it a go and see if that works better.

Comment: It works, but a bit laggy. I also plan not to use jQuery, is it a transition problem?

Comment: @JustinusHermawan It could be a transition problem, if i was you i would play around with it a bit more.

Comment: I solved it by using `height` property and added some logic to updated its height and their ancestors' height manually: https://codepen.io/justinus-hermawan/pen/RwoGKmq